# using javascript to truncate a paragraph in div to 100 characters

Tags: javascript, html

I have found the following script to limit / truncate my paragraphs of more than 400 chracters located in a `<div>` to 200 character.  But i can't figure out how to incorporate it in html!

How is this done?

Following is the script:

```
<script>
function ellipsify (str) {
    if (str.length > 10) {
        return (str.substring(0, 10) + "...");
    }
    else {
    return str;
}
}
</script>
```

Comment: if you dont care about the 100 chars but care about the space left in the element you can use css: [text-overflow: ellipsis;](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/text-overflow)

Comment: First you need to assign the text in div to a variable in JavaScript and pass that variable to the above function.

Comment: Pavlo showed in the answer for the usage of id.  But @Lalinda Sampath it only truncates the first div! How can the script be changed to change all divs?

Comment: make your second div's id as 'target2'. Then, var div2 = document.getElementById('target2');

Comment: That did it. Thank you @Lalinda Sampath

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that the div has id of "target":

```js
function ellipsify (str) {
    if (str.length > 10) {
        return (str.substring(0, 10) + "...");
    }
    else {
    return str;
}
}

var div = document.getElementById('target');
div.textContent = ellipsify(div.textContent);
```

```html
<div id="target">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</div>
```

More information about API's used:

- [document.getElementById](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById)
- [Node.textContent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent)

Comment: Thank you for your quick respond.  If I have more than one div, it only truncates the first div!  Is there a way to truncate all divs with that id?

Comment: Any idea how this could be done?  Should multiple java scripts be written for the number of divs needing to be truncated?